undefined dataLayer variables GTM
I'm using GTM to track purchase event from Snapchat in my store "Magento 2".
I've created a tag in GTM and it's fired but I got undefined variable !
I'm using this script in success.phtml
<script>
  dataLayer.push({
    'event':'purchase',
    'order_value':<?php echo $totall;?>,
    'order_id':<?php echo ($block->getOrderId()) ?>,
    'enhanced_conversion_data': {
      "email": <?php echo $email;?>,  
      "phone_number": <?php echo $phone;?>
    }
  })
</script>

The code above works fine when I check it through the browser it's returned a values.
But unfortunately the variables undefined in GTM !
I've tried to create a custom event trigger for success page but it's not fired:
Looking for you kind support.

Can you attach the screenshot about what you see in GTM preview? So you can see the purchase event but other fields are all undefined?
Also the screenshot about you see in the browser.

<script>
  dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'purchase',
    'order_value': '<?php echo $totall; ?>',
    'order_id': '<?php echo $block->getOrderId(); ?>',
    'enhanced_conversion_data': {
      'email': '<?php echo $email; ?>',  
      'phone_number': '<?php echo $phone; ?>'
    }
  });
</script>

My best guess is that a quote is missing in the PHP echo statement of this code, potentially leading to an error when pushing. Could you please check and fix it?

Hi @darreltw, It's returned a value when I check this code at success page.
So I think it's work fine.

Ok thanks. So we can rule out it is caused by wrong datalayer value. Still if you can upload some screenshots with preview it will help to debug. You can mask any important or sensitive data. Like  order_id: xxxxx
